# Compact, Connected, Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X$ Be compact, connected, Hausdorff, and have cut point $p$. Let $X-${$p$} be separated by $A$ and $B$.  Prove that $A$ and $B$ each have at least one non-cut point.

I know that I should post some effort but, I have nothing that I feel is remotely close to correct.

Comment: What is a cut point?

Comment: @ziggurism It's a point of a connected space such that $X-\{p\}$ is not connected.

Comment: So I assume that $A, B$ are both connected in order to talk about cut-points? So they are simply connected components of $X-\{p\}$ which are clopen?

Comment: Yes.  I think maybe a good way to do it is by contradiction.  So assume $A$ and $B$ have no non cut points. I then $A-${$a$}  is connected for all $a \in A$. Same idea for all $b \in B$. I am stuck after this though.

Comment: @Jerry: the negation of "all components have a non-cut point" is "there exists at least one components with no non-cut points", not "all components have no non-cut points"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let X be connected, compact, and Hausdorff. Cut points and separations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196086/let-x-be-connected-compact-and-hausdorff-cut-points-and-separations). Unfortunately the statement is not true by taking the wedge sum of two circles: $\infty$.

Comment: So it seems like the statement is not true?

Comment: @freakish I have looked at that problem. it was originally stated that $C$ has no cut points.  That is a false statement.  The original poster edited that hypothesis after someone pointed this out.  This is why I posted this question.  Thought it was interesting and I couldn't get anywhere with it.

Comment: @ziggurism your comment about the negation is correct.  Good catch. I wil edit the post to show this change.

Comment: I mean edit my comment

Comment: @Jerry The OP did a mistake but the counterexample is still valid. If you remove the center from the wedge of circles "$\infty$" then you end up with two pieces, each one of them is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ and as such has only cut points.

Comment: @ziggurism Indeed, the statement is false.

Comment: The correct statement is this: if $X$ is compact, connected (and possibly metrizable?) then $X$ has at least two non-cut points. But this is not trivial at all, see this: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC225168/pdf/pnas00124-0026.pdf at page 380.