# A continuum having a cut point

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This question is from Wayne Patty's Book q 13 Ex 4.2

> Question: A continuum is a compact , connected Hausdorff space. Let (X,T) be a continuum such that X contains atleast two points. Assume that X has a cut points p and let U and V be a separation of X-{p}.Show  that each of U and V contains a non-cut point.

I tried to do it by contradiction ie let both U and V don't have any non-cut points and let P and Q are it's separation.But I am not able to move foreward .

Please help with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let X be connected, compact, and Hausdorff. Cut points and separations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196086/let-x-be-connected-compact-and-hausdorff-cut-points-and-separations)

Comment: @MoisheKohan In fact these questions are identical. Bu it is not clear what is meant. If it means that $U$ contains a non-cut point of $U$, then we have a negative answer. If it means that $U$ contains a non-cut point of $X$, then we do not have an answer. I vote to close the question because it requires details.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Agree.